# Database design. How to approach this please?

Tags: mysql, database-design

I'm designing a database (MySQL) that will manage a fleet of vehicles.

Company has many garages across the city, at each garage, vehicles gets serviced (operation). An operation can be any of 3 types of services.

Table Vehicle, Table Garagae, Table Operation, Table Operation Type 1, Table Operation Type 2, Table Operation type 3.

Each Operation has the vehicle ID, garage ID, but how do I link it to the the other tables (service tables) depending on which type of service the user chooses?

I would also like to add a billing table, but I'm lost at how to design the relationship between these tables.

Answer (score 0):

If I have fully understood it I would suggest something like this (first of all you shouldn't have three operation tables):

```
Vehicles Table
- id
- garage_id

Garages Table
- id

Operations/Services Table
- id
- vehicle_id
- garage_id
- type

Customer Table
- id
- service_id

billings Table
- id
- customer_id
```

Comment: but depending on the operation, there may be different information associated with that op.

Comment: id as a field name is a SQL Antipattern.

Comment: SOME developers THINK it is an anti pattern... ;)

Answer (score 0):

You need six tables:

```
vechicle: id, ...
garage: id, ...

operation: id, vechicle_id, garage_id, operation_type (which can be 
one of the tree options/operations available, with the possibility to be extended)

customer: id, ...

billing: id, customer_id, total_amount
billingoperation: id, billing_id, operation_id, item_amount
```

You definitely should not creat three tables for operations. In the future if you would like to introduce a new operation that would involve creating a new table in the database.

Comment: please explain "which can be one of the tree options available, with the possibility to be extended"

Comment: and how do you store information that is specific to those individual operations?  You don't want a giant table with all possible columns for all possible operations

Comment: you can add another table: operationattribute with id, operation_id, ... The main problem with the three tables approach is that it's not scalable. If you want to generate some statistics for all operations you have to make three queries.

Answer (score 0):

For the record, I disagree with everyone who is saying you shouldn't have multiple operation tables.  I think that's perfectly fine, as long as it is done properly.  In fact, I'm doing that with one of my products right now.

If I understand, at the core of your question, you're asking how to do table inheritance, because Op Type 1 and Op Type 2 (etc.) IS A Operation.  The short answer is that you can't.  The longer answer is that you can't...at least not without some helper logic.

I assume you have some sort of program that will pull data from the database, rather than you just writing sql commands by hand.  Working under that assumption, let's use this as a subset of your database:

```
Garage
------
GarageId | GarageLocation | etc. 
---------|----------------|------
1        | 123 Main St.   | XX   

Operation
---------
OperationId | GarageId | TimeStarted | TimeEnded | OperationTypeDescId | OperationTypeId 
------------|----------|-------------|-----------|---------------------|----------------
2           | 1        | noon        | NULL      | 2                   | 2


OperationTypeDesc
-------------
OperationTypeDescId | Name  | Description
--------------------|-------|-------------------------
1                   | OpFoo | Do things with the stuff
2                   | OpBar | Do stuff with the things


OpFoo
-----
OpID | Thing1 | Thing2
-----|--------|-------
1    | 123    | abc

OpBar
-----
OpID | Stuff1 | Stuff2
-----|--------|-------
1    | 456    | def
2    | 789    | ghi
```

Using this setup, you have the following information:

- A garage has it's information, plain and simple
- An operation has a unique ID (OperationId), a garage where it was executed, an ID referencing the description of the operation, and the OperationType ID (more on this in a moment).
- A pre-populated table of operation types.  Each type has a unique ID (OperationTypeDescId), the name of the operation, and a human-readable description of what that operation is.
- 1 table for each row in OperationTypeDesc.  For convenience, the table name should be the same as the Name column

Now we can begin to see where inheritance comes into play.  In the operation table, the `OperationTypeId` references the `OpId` of the relevant table...the "relevant table" is determined by the OperationTypeDescId.

An example:  Let's say we had the above data set.  In this example we know that there is an operation happening in a garage at 123 Main St.  We know it started at noon, and has not yet ended.  We know the type of operation is "OpBar".  Since we know we're doing an OpBar operation instead of an OpFoo operation, we can focus on only the OpBar-relevant attributes, namely stuff1 and stuff2.  Since the Operations's OperationTypeId is 2, we know that Stuff1 is 789 and Stuff2 is ghi.

Now the tricky part.  In your program, this is going to require `Reflection`.  If you don't know what that is, it's the practice of getting a `Type` from the NAME of that type.  In our example, we know what table to look at (OpBar) because of its name in the OperationTypeDesc table.  Put another way, you don't automatically know what table to look in; reflection tells you that information.

**Edit:**
Csaba says "In the future if you would like to introduce a new operation that would involve creating a new table in the database".  That is correct.  You would also need to add a new row to the OperationTypeDesc table.  Csaba implies this is a bad thing, and I disagree - with a few provisions.  If you are going to be adding a new operation type frequently, then yes, he makes a very good point.  you don't want to be creating new tables constantly.  If, however, you know ahead of time what types of operations will be performed, and will very rarely add new types of operations, then I maintain this is the way to go.  All of your info common to all operations goes in the Operation table, and all op-specific info goes into the relevant "sub-table".

There is one more very important note regarding this.  Because of how this is designed, you, the human, must be aware of the design.  Whenever you create a new operation type, it's not as simple as creating the new table.  Specifically, you have to make sure that the new table name and the OperationTypeDesc "Name" entry are the same.  Think of it as an extra constraint - an "INTEGER" column can only contain ints, otherwise the db won't allow the data. In the same manner, the "Name" column can only contain the name of an existing table.  You the human must be aware of that constraint, because it cannot be (easily) automatically enforced.